# jQuery Draggable/Resizable clickthrough

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have an image with a parent div with the class `draggable` and `resizable` that jquery UI applies. This allows the div and image to be dragged and resize. However I also have a div inside the parent div that needs to execute a function when clicked.

```
<div class="draggable resizable ui-widget-content ui-resizable ui-draggable">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <div id="close_parent_div">x</div>
</div>
```

The problem seems to be that jquery draggable or resizable prevents the internal div from being clicked and executing. My question is, how do I get the internal div's function to run when clicked but also preserving the draggable/resizable functions.

Thanks

Comment: How you have tried. Can you please provide the code. It works for me. In script i have just make the dom draggable and resizable and bind a click event and it works fine.

Comment: Let me try again and then I'll post the full code